# How many minimized forms can a boolean expression have with 4 variables?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have this theoretical question I can't get my head around.

Assuming I have a function (any function) with 4 variables, and I draw a Karnaugh Map in order to extract the most simplified expression by selecting the correct PIs, how many possible forms could there be for a function with 4 variables ?

I figured: assuming none of your PIs are EPIs (Essential) that there would always be more than one way to express this function with the map (minimized form of course), however - does that mean there is only 2 ways ? no more ?

I was looking at some theoretical sources about the Karnaugh Map but I couldn't get a clear answer to my question.

Thanks in advance